# What is "gate length" in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-gate, terminology-and-notation

I am working on adding a new provider to Qiskit, and I have to specify the properties of the backend.
What is "gate length" (in ns) referring to?

Comment: It's the time needed to execute a certain gate.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as `Gate time` or the time needed to execute that certain gate.

If you look at the calibration data description of a specific device through the IBMQ website, and you will see that there is an option to see the CNOT gate time. For example, if you select your backend to be `ibmq_santiago` then you can see something like:
[image]

Note the $CNOT_{q0,q1}$ gate has the Gate time of 526 ns. And now if you extract the gate length from `backendproperties` of this gate, you get the same number. That is, if you run the following script:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
print(backend.properties().gates[26].name)
print(backend.properties().gates[26].parameters[1]  )
```

you get:

```
'cx0_1'
Nduv(datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 7, 30, 48, tzinfo=tzlocal()), gate_length, ns, 526.2222222222222)
```